# How to accumulate values tsql II

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have to solve a problem and don't know how to do it. Im using SQL Server 2012.

I have the data like this schema:

```
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   DriverId  | BeginDate | EndDate | NextBegin | Rest         | Drive Time | Drive
             |           |         | Date      | in minutes   | in seconds | KM            
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    integer     datetime   datetime   datetime    integer          integer     decimal(10,3)

   Rest in hours = EndDate - NextBeginDate
   Drive Time in Minutes = BeginDate - EndDate

   I have to search the BeginWorkDay first rest => 10 hours then
   BWD = BeginWorkDay
   EWD = EndWorkDay


   Do
     Compute how many minutes have the workDay (Diff between BWD and EWD) 
     SUM(DriveTime) as TotalDayDrive
     MAX(DriveTime) as MaxDriveDayPeriod
     SUM(Rest) as TotalDayRest
     Rest as NightRest
     MAX(Rest) as MaxDayRest
     Min(Rest) as MinDayRest
     SUM(TotalKM) as KM
   until next rest => 10 hours
   IF No More Rest EXIT DO
   Loop

Desired Result:

Driver     Plate    Begin Work Day            End Work Day             WorkDayTime(minu)
11953512       IVA870   2014-01-06 00:47:01.000   2014-01-06 11:08:32.000  621

DriveTime(seconds)   MaxDayDrive(sec)   TotalDayRest(minu)   NightRest(minu)   MinDayRest(minu)   
19081            3786               304              2.259             14              

MaxDayRest(minu)   KM
89                 138.200


DATA FILE                           
                Minutes Seconds 
DriverId   Plate   BeginDate    EndDate      NextBeginDate   Rest   DriveTime   DriveKM
11953512   IVA870  2014-01-04   2014-01-04   2014-01-06      2.259  2038    13.400
                   10:34:42.000 11:08:40.000 00:47:01.000    

11953512   IVA870  2014-01-06   2014-01-06   2014-01-06      89     2615    34.500
                   00:47:01.000 01:30:36.000 02:59:08.000   

11953512   IVA870  2014-01-06   2014-01-06   2014-01-06      51     2604    19.000
                   02:59:08.000 03:42:32.000 04:33:56.000

11953512   IVA870  2014-01-06   2014-01-06   2014-01-06      18     2294    17.500
                   04:33:56.000 05:12:10.000 05:30:42.000

11953512   IVA870  2014-01-06   2014-01-06   2014-01-06      47     2895    20.500
                   05:30:42.000 06:18:57.000 07:05:56.000    

11953512   IVA870  2014-01-06   2014-01-06   2014-01-06      47     2819    19.800
                   07:05:56.000 07:52:55.000 08:39:51.000   

11953512   IVA870  2014-01-06   2014-01-06   2014-01-06      14     239         0.300
                   08:39:51.000 08:43:50.000 08:57:05.000    

11953512   IVA870  2014-01-06   2014-01-06   2014-01-06      38     3786    18.000
                   08:57:05.000 10:00:11.000 10:38:03.000

11953512   IVA870  2014-01-06   2014-01-06   2014-01-07     843     1829    8.900
                   10:38:03.000 11:08:32.000 01:11:04.000
```

There is another theme "How to accumulate values tsql" where **Jerrad** wrote a charm script that solves a similar problem but I can't imagine how to modify this to work to solve this problem.

I have data in excel sheet you can download from here:[Download Excel with data example and desired result](http://www.tesma.com.ar/descargas/example2.xls)

I'm sorry for my english, I hope you can understand and help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Edit your question and add sample data and desired results.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, in the excel you will find example data an desired results. Thank you.

Comment: @Capanga You should include the example data and desired result in your question instead of in an outside link.  In the event that link is every down, it will be unhelpful to anyone with a similar issue.

Comment: Im sorry bluefeet, but is too much data to put in the question. Im going to put a little bit of the total data. Thank for your comment.

Comment: I'm very disappointed, you were very fast to disqualify my question, but didn't help. Thank you for nothing. I think, that this way we do not help anybody. Better shut my mouth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to identify the rows that make up each day.  I'm joining your data table to itself based on `BeginDate` and `NextBeginDate`.  This gives you the start and end datetimes for each day.  I'm storing the results in a CTE.

```
;with cte
as(
    select d.DriverId, 
    d.Matricula, 
    d.BeginDate DayBeginDate,
    (select MAX(EndDate) from Drive d3 where d3.DriverId = d.DriverId and d3.EndDate < DATEADD(d, 1, DATEDIFF(d, 0, d.BeginDate))) DayEndDate
    from Drive d 
    join Drive d2 on d.BeginDate = d2.NextBeginDate
    where d2.Rest > 600
)
```

Now it's just a matter of selecting the various aggregates from the main data table, based on the begin and end datetimes in the CTE.

```
select d.DriverId, 
d.Matricula, 
d.DayBeginDate, 
d.DayEndDate,
DATEDIFF(N, d.DayBeginDate, d.DayEndDate) WorkDayTime,
(select SUM(d2.DriveTime) from Drive d2 where d2.DriverId = d.DriverId and d2.BeginDate >= d.DayBeginDate and d2.EndDate <= d.DayEndDate) DriveTime,
(select MAX(d2.DriveTime) from Drive d2 where d2.DriverId = d.DriverId and d2.BeginDate >= d.DayBeginDate and d2.EndDate <= d.DayEndDate) MaxDayDrive,
(select SUM(d2.Rest) from Drive d2 where d2.DriverId = d.DriverId and d2.BeginDate >= d.DayBeginDate and d2.EndDate < d.DayEndDate) TotalDayRest,
DATEDIFF(N, (select MAX(d2.EndDate) from Drive d2 where d2.DriverId = d.DriverId and d2.EndDate < d.DayBeginDate), d.DayBeginDate) NightRest,
(select MIN(d2.Rest) from Drive d2 where d2.DriverId = d.DriverId and d2.BeginDate >= d.DayBeginDate and d2.EndDate < d.DayEndDate) MinDayRest,
(select MAX(d2.Rest) from Drive d2 where d2.DriverId = d.DriverId and d2.BeginDate >= d.DayBeginDate and d2.EndDate < d.DayEndDate) MaxDayRest,
(select SUM(d2.DriveKM) from Drive d2 where d2.DriverId = d.DriverId and d2.BeginDate >= d.DayBeginDate and d2.EndDate <= d.DayEndDate) KM
from cte d 
group by d.DriverId, d.Matricula, d.DayBeginDate, d.DayEndDate
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37ee1/6/0)

Comment: Hi Jerrad, thank you very much for your help. I will be testing this procedures later. I will leave a comment.

Comment: Hi Jerrad, on SQL Fiddle works fine, but in my computer Im having time  format problem its taking "2014-01-06 11:08:00" as "2014-01-06 23:08:00", can you help me to solve this? and the result is 1372 instead 621. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the data in the table correct, and just the query is showing the wrong time?  Did you import the data in SQL Server from the Excel file?

Comment: Yes, the data where copied from the table directly. If I consult the table the data says "2014-01-06 11:08:00" (on my pC) but the result from the query you create is "2014-01-06 23:08:00" for the same record (only in my PC". The first one is ok, the second is wrong. I dont know why, my PC setting is spain in 24 hs format. Only the query is wrong on my PC, but in SQL Fiddle is ok.

Comment: My Table for EndDate: 2014-01-06 11:08:32.000

Comment: Query EndDate: 2014-01-06 23:39:29.000

Comment: This are looking for the first day. I must receive 621 min and from query Im getting 1372.

Comment: What result do you get for this query?  select EndDate,
(select MAX(EndDate) from Drive d3 where d3.EndDate < DATEADD(d, 1, DATEDIFF(d, 0, d.BeginDate))) DayEndDate
from Drive d
where DriverId = 11953512
and BeginDate = '2014-01-06 10:38:03.000'

Comment: Nothing, I get no result

Comment: I have to go sleep, tomorow my work is waiting for me. If I can do anything else, please, let me know. I will try something more to see if I can get a solution. Thank you again.

Comment: It should give you something.  It's row 23 from the Excel file.

Comment: I use the complete select an shows 2014-01-06 23:39:29.000 for DayEndDate. Here is the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56650/discussion-between-jerrad-and-capanga).

Comment: Hi Jerrad, Im sorry to disturb you again, looks like there is a problem with the script, can you try to select DriverId number 4648622. Look at the BeginDayWork, we are having some repeated days (must be only one day) one of them have the info and the other only have the night rest and DayWorkTime this is wrong. Thank you